Ellipse to Parametric Form
If we have the equation $x^2+2y^2=4$, how would you translate that into Parametric Form?
I know that for a regular circle, the equation from $x^2+y^2=r^2$ translates into $(r \cos(t), r \sin(t))$, and I tried to change the $r$ value of the y value to make it shorter. Using Desmos and trial and error, I got to $(2 \cos(t), 1.411 \sin(t))$ which is close, but not quite there and I didn't use any formula.

If you use $y=\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}$, what would your equation then become?

HINT
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{2^2}\right) + \left(\frac{y^2}{(\sqrt2 )^2}\right)=1$$
